# how could I print all data in one line in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am practicing pl/sql programs .I have one program i.e.:
Example:

```
begin
    for i in 1..10
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
    end loop;
end;
```

the output is like this:

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
10
```

But I have to print all the numbers in one line i.e.(`123.....10`)
how could I archive this so, I will get the output is like this:`123...10`

Answer (score 9):

Use [`DBMS_OUTPUT.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#BABGHBIA):

```
SQL> begin
  2     for i in 1..10 loop
  3        dbms_output.put(i);
  4     end loop;
  5     dbms_output.new_line;
  6  end;
  7  /
12345678910

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

use .put(i) instead of put_line